# Why is my username/hostname in the SSH public key?

Tags: ssh

When generating a SSH key i used the `cat` command on the file `id_rsa.pub` and noticed the hostname/username of my account was within the file. Why is this there? If I was copying this onto a server wouldn't it make sense for this to not be here or be the hostname/username of the server? And the username to use with SSH? Am I going all about this wrong? My process is this:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-keygen
```

And then I write the generated `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys`
I finish up by copying over the key to the server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The last field in the ssh public key is a comment. By default it's initialized with the user@host value when the key was generated as a reminder. You can choose to edit it, it won't alter the key. This comment doesn't affect any authentication, it's only here to help manage multiple entries.

The location of the public key on the remote server is what affects it: it will allow access to the account where it was put inside its `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Only owning the private key will allow access to the remote account. There's no concept of which user access the account from the point of view of the server: the only relevant thing is that the SSH connection can be successfully established (using ssh key) only from an entity having the private key. If this private key was copied elsewhere (or stolen) it wouldn't make a difference. If you need access by ssh key from different users and/or systems to this account, don't copy the private key, just generate one per different location and add it to the `authorized_keys` file, it's better security hygiene.

Your method looks fine (you might also have to `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`) , but if you also have usual password access to the remote account, the easiest way to copy the ssh key is with the [`ssh-copy-id`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh-copy-id.1) command. For example to copy the default key to the *remoteuser* account on *remoteserver*:

```
ssh-copy-id remoteuser@remoteserver
```

which will automatically add the key to the remote account's `authorized_keys` file (creating it with correct access rights if not existing).

Comment: I can log into any user on the system using SSH if the private key belongs to  that of the public key within authorized_keys?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. I'll repeat it: the owner of the private key can access accounts where its public key counterpart has been put in the authorized_keys file.

Comment: So the owner of the private key can access any user account on the system the public key has been placed in authorized_keys?

Comment: yes, that's it.

Comment: Sorry but two more questions what about the private key how is it used? And does each user have a authorized_keys file? Will i have to write my public key to each user i want to use or just once?

Comment: it's for each user, not just once. For the key, there's plenty of documentation online about ssh. if you really don't find you should ask an other proper question